# Custom Get In NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, roblox, httpservice

So I'm making this API for http requests from roblox HttpService
but I don't know how to properly get user-defined gets? kinda like
luiboard.

```
OnxWebApp.get(`https://random_website.com${req}`, (req, res) => {
  Http.get(`https://random_website_lmao/users/${req.body}`, http_response => {
  
  })
})
```

I tried searching on nodejs documentation, youtube and other websites but couldn't get the solution

Comment: Please tell us a bit more what you've tried. What (unwanted) results you are getting now. There's plenty documentation, so point us to somewhere and explain why that does not work for you.